# Text Alignment lock in Sketch

Tags: sketch-app

Does anyone know why text Alignment can be locked?[image]

Comment: What do you mean? Why not?

Comment: Hi Alex, did my answer help you? If so, would you mind accepting it? Here's how: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

If the size of the text box is exactly what is required for the defined text size, it's locked. No idea why, it's strange to me too.

Simply resize the text box, set your target alignment and resize back to what you require.

Hope that helps!